# angularjs not loading immediately in liquid

Tags: angularjs, shopify, liquid

It takes some time for example first it loads angularjs as it and then load output.How i can improve it? First load:
[image]

after taking few seconds time output is correct:

[image]

```js
  
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  {[{ firstName + " " + lastName }]}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add `ng-cloak` to avoid it.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-cloak>

  {[{ firstName + " " + lastName }]}
</div>
```

Comment: @SufyanAhmad you are welcome, don't forget to accept it as answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

ng-cloak will do that job for you, it doesn't let angular expressions to print on view, read the documentation for more details:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

you can use it for whole body or on elements as well like:

```html
<div ng-cloak> {{someExpression}} </div>
```